# storyboard is missing from visual studio and backlog is missing in team explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, team-explorer

when I installed visual studio premium 2012 PowerPoint storyboard were installed for the first time,, 
today I can't find it,  it is missing.
 plus I can't find backlog in team explorer ,,
and the board in team explorer is empty , how can  I show it.